# Does navigator.webkitPersistentStorage.requestQuota apply to IndexedDB?

Tags: google-chrome, local-storage, google-chrome-app, indexeddb, persistent-storage

With today's latest version of Chrome for Android, can I request for persistent IndexedDB storage with `navigator.webkitPersistentStorage.requestQuota`?

```
var requestedBytes = 1024*1024*1024; 

navigator.webkitPersistentStorage.requestQuota (
    requestedBytes, function(grantedBytes) {  
        console.log('we were granted ', grantedBytes, 'bytes');

    }, function(e) { console.log('Error', e); }
);
```

Or, does `navigator.webkitPersistentStorage.requestQuota` still only apply to the `FileSystem API`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`navigator.webkitPersistentStorage.requestQuota` is only for the sandboxed filesystem api.

You want the new `navigator.storage.persist()` api which applies to all site storage.

https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2016/06/persistent-storage