# Grant unlimited persistence storage permission

Tags: android, cordova, webview, indexeddb

Based on the [IndexedDB of Cordova Storage](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/7.x/cordova/storage/storage.html#indexeddb) documentation, the storage is limited to around 5MB (the last point of the Disadvantages paragraph).

I need far more storage for my app, thus I have to break the jail without any other option.

Round 1: Ask for more storage quota.

```
navigator.webkitPersistentStorage.requestQuota(quota, function(granted) {
    window.requestFileSystem(window.PERSISTENT, granted, cbSucc, cbErr);
}, cbErr);
```

1. The 'granted' alway zero no matter what 'quota' is.
2. There is no requestFileSystem() function in the 'window' object on Android webview.
3. Based on (https://stackoverflow.com/a/42355894) : it only works for the sandboxed filesystem. Maybe this is not what I need anyway.

Round 2: Implement a Push Notification service worker which will grant persistence storage permission automatically.

```
navigator.serviceWorker.register('sw.js')
.then(function(swNotify) {
    swNotify.pushManager.subscribe({
        userVisibleOnly : true,
        applicationServerKey : pubKey
    });
});
```

1. The service worker is registered.
2. There is no PushManager on Android webview, thus no way to do pushManager.subscribe().
3. This works fine for Chrome on desktop and Android except webview.

Round 3: Ask for durable storage permission.

```
navigator.storage.persist().then(...);
```

1. The persist() function always returns false without asking user to grant permission.
2. The WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission is already requested and granted.

Environment :

- Android: 7.0 (by Android Emulator)
- WebView: 58.0.3029.83
- Cordova: 7.0.1
- andorid platform of Cordova: 6.2.3

I am still a prisoner of the 5MB jail, what can I do else?

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [cordova-sqlite-storage](https://github.com/litehelpers/Cordova-sqlite-storage) plugin to create a native SQLite database with unlimited storage:

Unlike IndexedDB (and WebSQL) which are integrated into the Webview, this uses a native database which is stored in a `.db` file on disk.

Currently there is no IndexedDB interface shim (although it's on the [TODO list](https://github.com/litehelpers/Cordova-sqlite-storage#major-todos)) so you'd need to rework the API calls to the database. However there is, for example, an [adapter](https://github.com/litehelpers/cordova-sqlite-lawnchair-adapter) for [Lawnchair](http://brian.io/lawnchair/) which makes for an easy-to-use API.

Comment: Thank you Dave but I think replace a NoSQL with a RDB may not a good ideal. It has to rework starting from system architecture.

Comment: Lawnchair gives you a key/value storage interface (akin to IndexedDB). The actual underlying DB may be a RDB but this is irrelevant since the interface to it is abstracted to be non-relational.